# Set of left cosets is a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $G/N = \{gN : g \in G \}$. Show that the $(G/N, \circ, 1_{G/N})$ is a group, where:

$\circ : G/N \times G/N \rightarrow G/N$ is defined by $(gN \circ hN) = ghN$
and $1_{G/N} = 1*N$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First verify that the group operation is well-defined, that is, show that the correspondence from $G/N\to G/N$ is actually a function. Assume for $a,a',b,b'\in G$ we have $aN=a'N,bN=b'N$. We must verify that $aNbN=a'Nb'N$, or $abN=a'b'N$. This step is necessary because when we are dealing with cosets, we must ensure that our function definition depends only on the cosets, and *not the coset representatives*.

For this part, note that if $aN=a'N$, $bN=b'N$, then $a=a'n_1$ and $b=b'n_2$ for some $n_1,n_2\in N$. Therefore $a'b'N=an_1bn_2N=an_1bN=an_1Nb=aNb=abN$, using associativity and the fact that $N$ is normal in $G$.

From here it should be easy to verify that the three group properties hold:

1. Identity: $N\quad ((gN)(N)=gN)$
2. Inverses: $(gN)^{-1}=g^{-1}N\quad (gNg^{-1}N=gg^{-1}N=N)
   $
3. Associativity: $gN(hNkN)=ghkN=(gNhN)kN$

Comment: Those things are not actually the most important things to check here (note that none of them use that $N$ is normal).

Comment: @AndreasCaranti That comment was to an earlier version of the answer.

Comment: @zach, the function to be check for the well-definition is $G/N \times G/N \to G/N$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, good point. I've revised the answer.

Comment: Thanks, the confusing property for me is the inverse. Here's my attempt: (gN$)^{-1}$ $\circ$ (gN) = $g^{-1}$gN = 1*N = N

Comment: @kbball, that's right. The group operation makes it that easy. You might say Claim: $(gN)^{-1}=g^{-1}N$. Then show that $gNg^{-1}N=gg^{-1}N=N$, as you did. Be careful not to assume what you are trying to show.